# GitHub RAW file URL not working for files in a Private Repository

Tags: git, api, github, github-api

While working with GitHub REST APIs, I got the comparison of all the files involved in a commit using the commit difference endpoint given as following:

https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/compare/hubot:branchname...octocat:branchname

But I also need to get the full files both from parent and child commit. GitHub returns a raw file URL in the results of the commit difference API:

https://github.com/ahmad7428/:repo/raw/:commithash/:filePath

The problem is that these URLs work with files in public repos but return 404 for files in private repos. I'm trying to get the files by consuming the minimum number of GitHub endpoints. How can do it? or How should I do it?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example, as `https://api.github.com/api/v1` has been obsolete for a while. It's also not clear whether you are making authenticated API calls, as those may or may not work depending on whether you have access to the repository.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please have a look now

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that these URLs work with files in public repos but return 404 for files in **private** repos.

This is the key to your issue. You need to be authenticated and have permissions to access the repository to access these URLs. It's not clear to me that you're doing that.

The "raw" in this context means it'll return the file contents at a given commit, rather than viewing the file history on GitHub.

> How can do it? or How should I do it?

Are you making the request using a token that has access to that repository? If you're not authenticated GitHub will just return a 404